# php more than 5 items create new div

Tags: php

I am using PHP and MYSQL.
here is my code

```
 <?php 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `item` order by `ID` limit 0, 5");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows ($result); 
    $item = 0 ; 

     while ($item < $rows){

        $title = mysql_result($result,$list,"name");
        $id = mysql_result($result,$list,"ID");
        echo "<div id="new"> $id . $title  </div> ";

     $item++;
    }
     ?>
```

My question is that, is it possible if the items are more than 5 (as you can see I limited items), then create a new div id=new to display the rest items?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `while()` loop this way:

```
 echo '<div>'; // Starting DIV
 while ($item < $rows){
    $title = mysql_result($result,$list,"name");
    $id = mysql_result($result,$list,"ID");
    echo "<div id="new"> $id . $title  </div> ";
    $item++;
    echo ($item % 5 == 0) ? '</div><div>' : ""; // Close and Open a New DIV
}
echo '</div>'; // Ending DIV
```

Happy to Help! :)

Comment: thank you  Praveen Kumar, I will try it tonight. does it loop every 5 items? thanks again

Comment: Yes, and that is the reason, I have given this part: `echo ($item % 5 == 0) ? '</div><div>' : "";`

Comment: Hi Praveen, could you please explain a bit "$item % 5 == 0", which means "3 == 0"? don't quite understand this part. thank you

Comment: Hi @olo, it is actually this way. It is modulus operator. So, it returns the remainder of a division. So, when you wanna do something once in `n` times, then, when you divide the `count` by the `n`, the value will always be from `0` to `n`. And if you wanna do a break at `n` multiples, always the value will be `0`. Like `5 % 5 = 0`. You understood the logic?